# parsing issue in JsonLayout(log4j.xml) using fluent-bit deamon

Tags: java, json, xml, log4j, fluent-bit

Hey Im getting issue while parsing JsonLayout(log4j.xml) using fluent-bit deamon

I tried finding in doc but couldn't find any fix
this is my JsonLayout

```
<JsonLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true">
     <KeyValuePair key="wx.server.type.test" value="TEST"/>
      <KeyValuePair key="wx.server.status.test" value="active"/>
 </JsonLayout>
```

with this Im getting output like this in opensearch

```
{"wx_server_type_test":"TEST","wx_server_status_test":"active"}
```

but In need output like this

```
{"wx.server.type.test":"TEST","wx.server.status.test":"active"}
```

any lead will be helpful thanks